# ECG / EEG Amplifier design tricks

Tags: analog, ecg, cmrr, eeg

First of all, sorry, I missed the links / images where I have found the solutions mentioned below (I hope, if you are familiar with this topic, you know them):

I have to design an ECG / EEG analog amplifier with a gain around 1000. Sigma-Delta is the preferred AD converter architecture. As I search trough the net, I see some implementation, where:

- the input is AC coupled trough RC high pass filter
- the instrumental amplifier's reference pin is driven by an integrator (servo feedback)
- after that an active high pass filter is realized

The design tread off that I cannot decide / I don't understand (we know, every components add noise to the signal present on the output):

- as the input should be AC coupled due to electrode offset cancellation, why should I apply servo drive and HP filter?
- some designs throw away the AC coupling, but requires lower instrumental amplifier gain, that reduce CMRR
- some another designs left the servo drive and connect the instrumental amplifier's reference to a predefined potential

Can somebody help me to decide about these solutions / constraints?

Regards

Edit:
This is my concept design:
[image]

User69795 said:

> The problem with the high pass filter in this application is due to the very slow response time of the filter ... When the input is overdriven, ... the filter takes a really long time to settle, so the signal output is not visible to the doctors, so they don’t know if the patient is still in fibrillation or is dead or is OK.
>
> Overcoming this response time problem while still providing the correct high pass filtering leads to the different ways of implementing the high pass function that you have noticed. A good solution calls for clever design.

As I understand you correctly, the C15 R13 U4A HP filter should be removed due to the large settling time?
And what about the AC coupled input and the common to differential mode transformation caused by the component mismatch?

Comment: Do you need to design the amplifier itself or just make an ECG/EEG device? If the latter, then there are off the shelf chips for measuring biopotentials like ADS1194.

Comment: If "As I understand you ..." is a response to a reply or comment you should say so. As it is peop;e rading t do not know what you are referring to. It can be useful to co[y in a small part of what you are responding to and prefix it with ">" symbol which marks the block. I have added a short example to your question. Remove or alter as desired.

Comment: The goal is to develop an ECG like device (due to proprietary reasons let's say "ECG like")
where I have to measure the signal with at least 16-20 bit resolution. If I use ADS1194, ADS1299 or similar AFE, the signal in interest will be represented on 5-10 bits.
So I have to design an amplifier to its output signal span the input range of the AD converter.

Comment: I prefer *not* AC coupling.  Rather, I use a modest gain inamp for an input stage, then HPF, then more gain.

Comment: ECG generally includes DC

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the high pass filter in this application is due to the very slow response time of the filter (because the filter is at such a low frequency).  When the input is overdriven, ( for example, when the patient is defibrillated), the filter takes a really long time to settle, so the signal output is not visible to the doctors, so they don’t know if the patient is still in fibrillation or is dead or is ok.

Overcoming this response time problem while still providing the correct high pass filtering leads to the different ways of implementing the high pass function that you have noticed. A good solution calls for clever design.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the servo: IMO the point is to tackle DC offset of the input amp, and maybe other sources of offset.

Any op-amp has some minuscule DC offset to its input, and the offset is not constant, it may feature a temperature drift. This offset gets amplified by the amplifier's gain, set by the resistive network in the relevant negative feedback. While the DC offset is no problem at low levels of gain, it can cause quite some asymmetry if you set the gain higher. Yes you can still AC-couple your negative feedback network to GND using a capacitor, thus forming a high-pass filter, and thus limiting DC gain to 0 dB... anyway a slow servo from the very output to the input amp will get rid of the DC offset forever, and you can even DC-couple the whole signal chain.

Instrumentation amplifiers tend to have a really low DC offset... but never a complete zero. Also, I'm not familiar with sensing tiny potentials on biological substrates (human skin), it would be nice to know what the sensors look like, and what potential / attachment point serves as a reference ground for your amplifier inputs... (okay, there's something called the Wilson Central Terminal). If there's a risk of DC potentials forming between the biology and your electrode (electrochemical potential, kind of thing), and these might be variable, that's another possible reason for a servo.

So the servo may be a good way to tackle the DC offset wholesale :-)

Makes me wonder if the order of the high-pass filter plays a role. Maybe a steeper filter is desired. Basic RC gives you just 6 dB/oct if memory serves. Which would be another point in favour of a servo...

In amplifiers that need to harvest weak signals, you generally need to choose an input stage with minimal own noise (unfortunately high input impedance is a conflicting criterion) and provide some non-trivial gain in this "LNA" stage, so that own noise contributed by subsequent amp stages becomes irrelevant.

Finally, I'd like to recommend [the datasheet of the ADS1194](https://www.ti.com/product/ADS1194), as mentioned by @filo - an interesting read, with a number of references to "state of the art" and terminology in the ECG business.

Comment: For Biopotentials, there can be junction potentials at the skin/electrode interface  that are all too real.  I like to design in about 150mV of electrode offset into the design.  It's safe to assume the electrodes are Ag/AgCl  electrodes (i.e., nonpolarizing)